# Laravel Artisan Command for simple Migration?

Tags: laravel, automation, migration

Is there a **command/package** for laravel that simplifies or automates simple Laravel migrations ?

Example : `"php artisan migration:addfield --table: Posts --field: date_birth etc/parameters ..."`

The goal is to simplify and automate simple actions like making small changes to tables, for example.

There is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this package, which is created by Jeffrey Way (owner of Laracasts)

https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking a for a field to add in existing table ??Then use this

```
php artisan make:migration add_date_of_birth_to_posts_table --table=posts
```

You can directly mention the table without --table tag

```
php artisan make:migration add_date_of_birth_to_posts
```